# Magento: Retrieve custom checkout attributes

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

I'm using the [AITOC Custom Checkout Extension](http://www.aitoc.com/en/magentomods_checkoutfieldsmanager.html) for Magento and I'm trying to retrieve my custom attributes in a script.

My code so far:

```
$orderItems = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $from, 'to' => $to))
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->load();

// Retrieve customer name
foreach ($orderItems as $order) {
    $order_data = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order['order_id']);
    echo $order_data->getCustomerName();
}
```

This works great but I can't find a way to retrieve the custom checkout attributes.

Any ideas on how this could be done?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

The below image is from the AITOC docs on how to retrieve info using the Magento API. I would like to do exact this without using the API.

[image]

Comment: What's a custom checkout attribute?  Are they being saved to the order model (i.e. in sales_order_flat table)?  You could try `var_dump(array_keys($order_data->getData()))` to see what's readily available.

Comment: @SteveRobbins I don't see them there so I guess not. They say in their docs that one get the data from the Magento API sales_order.info or sales_order.list. I have updated my question with the doc. Any ideas how I can retrieve the info without using the API?

Comment: @SteveRobbins another thing I noticed is that the custom attributes can be found under "Addtional info" in the magento admin.

Comment: What's the name of one of the attributes? I still don't quite understand the question.  Also, if they're doing it in the API, take a look and see if you can replicate how it's done in `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Api::info()`

Comment: "businessunit" is the name of one of the attributes. Ok, good idea. I will check and see if I find something. Thanks